# Should we [capitalize] on the opportunity to merge these tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I've found out there are 2 tags for capitalization issues: [capitalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capitalize) and [capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capitalization).

Is there a valid reason for having both of them? If so, is that reason clear enough for people writing questions so that they are not mistaken?

Should they be synonymized?

Comment: and they should be spelt capitalise... But, I'm never going to win that one.

Comment: It is still hapenning, I would suggest a synonyms but I don't have reputation enough in those tags to do so. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/capitalization/synonyms

Comment: Related, but not identical, as this deals with a lot of other tags: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307151/up-with-capitalization

Answer (score 2):

Both look like useless tags to me with 0 followers. I'd burn them rather than make them synonyms.

Anyone that finds questions related to them will be finding them via a specific language where coding around capitalisation (sorry that's the Queen's English) will be different. The tags add little value as nobody is a specialist in CaPiTaLiSaTiOn.

[164 Questions for Capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capitalization)

[109 Questions for Capitalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capitalize)

**Total of 273 questions**

[image]

<sub>*love that tune - no copyright infringement intended*</sub>

Comment: I think there are experts in capitalization. Most programmers only have a very shallow understanding of the subject, but there are plenty of subtle points.