# UP WITH [CAPITALIZATION]!

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

This concerns some [2,694 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:question+[capitalization]+or+[capitalize]+or+[lowercase]+or+[mixed-case]+or+[uppercase]+or+[title-case]+or+[case-folding]+or+[case-conversion]+or+[case-sensitive]+or+[case-insensitive]+or+[ignore-case]+or+[sentencecase]+or+[capslock]+or+[upcase]) today, in 16 tags (+1 synonym) that are all related to upper & lower case text.

Some of these tags were previously discussed in [Merging [case-sensitive] and [case-insensitive] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281064/merging-case-sensitive-and-case-insensitive-tags).

I propose the bulk of these tags be removed or made synonyms, as they add no value to categorizing or finding answers. The fact is, there are many more questions that are relevant that **are not** sporting any of these tags. Consider:

- About [9,000 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-[capitalize]+capitalize) containing "capitalize" but not tagged [capitalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capitalize).
- Almost [28,000 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-[uppercase]+uppercase) containing "uppercase" but not tagged [uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uppercase).
- More than [28,000 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-[lowercase]+lowercase) containing "lowercase" but not tagged [lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lowercase). (The counts are coincidental.)
- etc.

The only real problem here is the abundance of overlapping and redundant tags; we can anticipate a high level of duplication due to the subject matter, but generally the questions appear to be good. The discussion needed is whether to de-tag, re-tag or synonym-ize, and which tags to keep, if any. (Personally, if it were up to me to choose one tag to rule them all, I would select [capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capitalization).)

#### Tag details

- [capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capitalization)  0 followers, 223 questions, *Capitalization means changing each first letter of a string to a capital letter.*

  - Not entirely correct according to dictionary.com, which says "to write or print in capital letters letters or with an initial capital."
- [capitalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capitalize)  0 followers, 145 questions, *Capitalize is writing a word with its first letter as a capital letter (upper-case letter) and the remaining letters in lower case.*

  - A small number of these ([8 currently](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[capitalize]+[ruby]+is%3Aquestion)) are about Ruby's `string.capitalize()`.
- [uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uppercase) 1 follower, 578 questions, *Uppercase characters are capital letters.*
- [lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lowercase)  1 follower, 442 questions. *Lowercase characters are letters in minuscule: a, b, c, …*
- [mixed-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed-case) 0 followers, 5 questions, *For issues with strings containing both lower-case and upper-case characters.*
- [title-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/title-case) 0 followers, 36 questions, *In string or sentence formatting, title case is the term used for capitalizing the first character of each principal word.*
- [toupper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toupper) 0 followers, 66 questions, *In C / C++ toupper function converts a given character to uppercase according to the character conversion rules defined by the currently installed C locale. In the default "C" locale, the following lowercase letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz are replaced with respective uppercase letters ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.*
- [tolower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tolower)  0 followers, 68 questions, *In C / C++ tolower function converts a given character to lowercase according to the character conversion rules defined by the currently installed C locale. In the default "C" locale, the following uppercase letters ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ are replaced with respective lowercase letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.*
- [case-folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-folding) 0 followers, 8 questions, *Questions related to the case-insensitve comparison and use of strings.*
- [case-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-conversion) 0 followers, 9 questions, *no wiki*
- [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-sensitive) 1 follower, 746 questions, *An operation is case sensitive when uppercase and lowercase characters are treated differently.*

  - Synonym: [case-sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-sensitivity)
- [case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-insensitive)  2 followers, 612 questions, *An operation is case insensitive when uppercase and lowercase characters are equally treated.*
- [ignore-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore-case)  0 followers, 42 questions, *A method that ignores case when comparing two strings.*
- [sentencecase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sentencecase) 0 followers, 6 questions, *no wiki*.
- [capslock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capslock) 0 followers, 92 questions, *Caps lock is a lock key found on many computer keyboards, depending on the local keyboard layout they implement.*

  - This tag may deserve to remain separate; the tagged questions are generally focused on dealing with hardware (or simulated hardware, e.g. smartphone keyboards), rather than programmatic manipulation of strings. It's included for completeness of the discussion.
  - Side problem: The wiki appears to be plagiarized from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caps_lock) without attribution, and is largely irrelevant.
- [upcase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upcase)  0 followers, 12 questions, *no wiki*

  - This is a Ruby-specific method. Other case-related string methods in Ruby which *don't* have their own tags are `downcase` and `swapcase`. There are 8 Ruby-tagged questions in [capitalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capitalize) which appear to be about `string.capitalize()`.

Comment: Upcase can also refer to a function in the [Unidata/Rocket software SOUL language](http://m204wiki.rocketsoftware.com/index.php/$Upcase)

Comment: @JGreenwell - It could also apply to a Ruby training organization... but while the tag could be ambiguous, all the current questions are about the Ruby method.

Comment: Somewhat related: tags [camelcasing](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/camelcasing/info) and [camelcase](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/camelcasing/info)

Comment: The description of [tag:case-folding] is *sic* the spelling error ...

Comment: @pnuts: It seems that there are actually two topics here: case detection, and case conversion, aka `isupper()` and `toupper()`.  All the other uses fall into one of these.

Comment: Upcase is a thing in Common Lisp as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt - that looks like a useful way to categorize these things language-independently.

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT!! Oh wait... right... gotcha. Never mind.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I can't believe it took that long for someone to say that... Thanks!

Comment: Down with this sort of thing!

Answer (score 19):

I originally wrote:

> [All (or at least most) of these tags should be wiped from the front and back ends of SO.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304229/173497)
>
> Really, no one is following these tags because they have important contributions to make with their specific expertise.

Except there is actually a frightening amount of expertise related to things like [Unicode equivalence](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Unicode_equivalence), at least for non-English, and non-Latin alphabet languages. But none of the tags you listed seem appropriately general. Perhaps [text-normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-normalization)? That tag actually has 13 questions already. For all of the tags that don't match function or method names in some language, I think we should make them synonyms of that tag. It's general enough that it covers all of the other tags and it's actually something about which some people could be expected to legitimately have expertise worth sharing.

I'm inclined to think that [capslock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capslock) can't really be that useful. There's nothing really special about <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> in any of the questions with that tag, other than that's just the key the askers wanted to use or detect. Surely we don't need tags for <kbd>Shift</kbd>* (or – *shudder* – <kbd>Enter</kbd> [[Fuck! Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enter)]).

* Well *of course* there over 500 questions tagged [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift)! And a lot of the top questions don't have anything to do with the keyboard keys, despite the tag description. Bleh!

Comment: I'd just assume [tag:shift] would pertain to bit-shifting, silly me.

Comment: @Mogsdad: Shift is amazing. Second page (for me) shows a question about *scheduling shifts at work*.

Comment: Let's see your [tag:shift] and I'll raise that with [tag:space].

Comment: [Get shwifty](https://www.reddit.com/r/rickandmorty/comments/3i5pl1/its_time_to_get_shwifty/).

Comment: @Jongware The space tag made me die a little inside. I just found a question that's tagged with space because the asker is trying to make a game similar to Space Invaders. Edit: And two more...

Comment: From my limited Unicode experience, I believe that changing the case of text and normalizing it are different things. Maybe "text manipulation" ?

Comment: Yes, most of them should go, but which **one** will remain? Obviously people want to use a tag, so if we leave one that contains at least 'case', autocompletion will suggested it when people start typing cas.... I'm not sure which one though. 'case' is already taken. Maybe 'character case'? Ugly, but fits the bill.

Comment: @JanDoggen They could be made synonyms of one tag instead in which case (ha) they'd still be usable.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think you're somewhat right, but I haven't found a word or phrase that includes both text normalization and "changing the case of text". I think text normalization might still be arguably the best phrase as capitalizing text, in general, is much easier after the input text has first been normalized. Obviously there are simple tasks covered by questions with one of these tags that aren't really asking about anything that complicated, but they're the ones that probably don't need these tags anyways.